# ekf_localization_node navsat_transform_node

Tags: ros, navigation, ekf, navsat-transform, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Tom! Remember mi system:
-I have a IMU microstrain 3DMGX2
-GPS
-I want integrate with ekf

My configuration:

**ekf_localization_node**

```
-Inputs
    IMU/DATA output
    Tnavsat_transform_node output

-Outputs
    Odometry message
```

**navsat_transform_node**

```
-Inputs
    IMU/DATA output
    nmea serial GPS (NavSatFix)
    Odometry message

-Outputs
    odometry gps
```

With rqt graph i can see:

[image: image description]

Then i include a broadcasting transform base_link -> IMU and when i do this mi rqt graph change:
[image: image description]

When i echo gps/odometry not is correct, i need to do other broadcast?
In upload to dropbox my launch file and debug:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ab23ou7fo7nw2cd/AAD722h-vmk0dCveJaWuOfZBa?dl=0

Thanks

EDIT 2: when I point to the imu towards magnetic north, on the positive x serial cable the opposite side. imu get data through the following:
X: 0
Y: 0
Z: 0.7
W: 0.7
Is it right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204073/ekf_localization_node-navsat_transform_node/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-03-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-03-02**:
Removed the comments for easier reading.

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-03-03**:
I simplified the nodes and included the rostopic echo. Thank you very much

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-03-10**:
I think you're going to need to be more descriptive than "is not correct." What exactly is wrong with it? Is it always zero? Does it jump around too much? Feel free to record and post a bag file and I'll take a look when I get a chance.

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-03-14**:
The odometry/filtered is giving a consistent value and suddenly begins to increase much and then returns to converge to values ​​consistent . I leave a link with a rosbag where you can view all the topics . Thank You https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjqd6lc6tqtojz2/viernes13_3.bag?dl=0

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-03-17**:
Cool, I'll check it out soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you post a sample IMU message? At first glance, I'd say you should get rid of your *xxx_rejection_threshold* settings. As for your question about `tf`, `ekf_localization_node` publishes a `tf` transform from the *world_frame* to the *base_link_frame*, and `navsat_transform_node` (optionally) publishes a transform from the UTM grid to your world frame. Even though you have that parameter set to false, the TransformBroadcaster object gets declared anyway, and I'm guessing that's enough to cause the graph to draw the arrow.

EDIT in response to updates/comments: the rejection thresholds are intended to help reject outlier measurements. Given your measurement sources, I don't think you need them. Just delete them from your launch file.

I think you should back up and try one thing at a time. Just run `ekf_localization_node`, and start with just your IMU. Make sure that it's producing output, and then move on to integrating the `navsat_transform_node`. And to answer what I think you were asking, yes, if you have some other source of odometry for your robot, then you should definitely fuse that as well.

EDIT 2: The [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) message uses quaternions to represent orientations. This is common in ROS. If you want to transform it, you'll need to write a node that takes in the quaternion and converts it. Alternatively, you can use `tf_echo` to listen to the *world_frame*->*base_link_frame* transform being broadcast by `ekf_localization_node`. `tf_echo` does the conversion for you.

For the GPS, no, you don't currently need a *base_link*->*gps* transform.

EDIT 3 (in response to comments): I'm afraid I don't understand. What do you mean by you "adapted an EKF"? `ekf_localization_node` and `navsat_transform_node`  are all you should need. Do `rostopic echo /odometry/gps`. If it's not publishing, then `navsat_transform_node` isn't getting all the data it needs, or there's an issue with the data it's getting. As to whether I'll revise the code, if you meant that I should fix `navsat_transform_node`, I think it's more likely that there's an issue with the data. If you meant can I revise your code, I'm afraid I don't have the spare time.

EDIT 4: After looking at your debug file, I have a few notes:

1. Your position is definitely *not* 0. I don't know what topic you're listening to or for how long, but if you search through the debug file for "Corrected full state is," you'll see that it's definitely integrating your GPS and IMU data, and that your positions are not 0. Are you certain you're echoing the right topic?
2. That said, the GPS odometry messages that are coming in are all over the place. Not sure why. Have you plotted raw data from all your sensors to make sure the incoming data is correct?
3. Your IMU data has incorrect accelerations. If you have it mounted flat, then your linear acceleration should be +9.81 for Z. Are you using a Microstrain GX2? Try [this](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu) fork. Your accelerations and velocities are exploding.
4. I think you might benefit from reading through all the robot_localization [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials) again, and pay particular attention to the sections on preparing your sensor data.

EDIT 5: No, when the sensor faces magnetic north, the quaternion values should be close to (0, 0, 0, 1), which is equivalent to 0 roll, 0 pitch, and 0 yaw. Why don't we take this offline and update the question and answer when we've figured it out? Please use my e-mail address on the wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-03-03**:
When I connect the imu with single ekf not get to have / odometry / filtered. I have to throw something other than the node imu and the ekf? Or make a call to a service or change any settings?
Thanks for your time

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-03-03**:
No. One sensor is enough. If you're not getting output, then something is wrong. Are you broadcasting a transform from *base_link*->*imu*?

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-03-03**:
I'm broadcasting a transform from base_link->imu, now i need euler angles because is more easy to interpret. When i want integrate a GPS i need broadcasting a transform from base_link->gps too?

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-03-05**:
Thanks for all the help that you proporcionadao me. I'm using the same IMU that you and I want to place in the center of the vehicle, the transformed I do is correct? Because the message odometry filtered and leaves the imu are not consistent. The launch tf is above

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-03-05**:
Your parameters to `static_transform_publisher` are wrong. It accepts two different parameter sets. One lets you specify Euler angles, and one lets you specify a quaternion. You are using the quaternion, but have the 1 in *qX* location, when it should be the *qW* location.

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-03-06**:
I´ve corrected it and when i see the frames with rviz is right!! Thanks. Now i want integrate gps with navsat, i adapted a ekf for this but when i see odometry filtered the position x and y is 0. However gps/odometry is true. Can you revise the code?

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-03-06**:
Ok thanks, asked if he thought my launch parameters are fine.
When I echo on odometry / gps values are correct, but when I echo on odometry / filtered position is always 0 in X and Y. I've already edited the launch with nodes that I throw. Thank You

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-03-06**:
Set debug mode to true, run your launch file, wait until a few /odometry/gps messages have been published, stop everything, and then post the debug output file using DropBox or something similar.

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-03-07**:
Ok! Thanks! https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ab23ou7fo7nw2cd/AAD722h-vmk0dCveJaWuOfZBa?dl=0

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-03-25**:
I sent you  email! One more thing What axis of IMU points to magnetic north? X or Y. Thanks

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-03-25**:
I'm aware. I've been busy with work and will respond when I get a chance.